# Symfony Serializer->denormalize() in EntityListener postLoad method does not work within phpunit Integration test

Tags: unit-testing, symfony, deserialization

I have an EntityListener with a `postLoad` method like this:

```
public function postLoad(AntragInterface $antrag): void
    {
        if ($antrag->getDataRaw()) {
            $data = $this->serializer->denormalize(
                $antrag->getDataRaw(),
                $this->dataClass,
            );

            $antrag->setData($data);
        } else {
            $antrag->setData(new $this->dataClass());
        }
    }
```

I inject the serializer in the constructor:

```
public function __construct(
    private Security $security,
    protected SerializerInterface $serializer,
    protected string $dataClass,
) {}
```

`dataRaw` is a json field in a maria db. That value is converted into an associative array by doctrine. The array should then be denormalized into an Object of the class in `$this->dataClass`. That works just fine in the application.

But when I run an integration test with phpunit, the serializer does not seem to be initialized properly. It says it has no Normalizer and when I define a normalizer for the tag `serializer.normalizer` in services_test.yaml it still doesn't seem to have a `propertyTypeExtractor`.

For my test class I extend the `KernelTestCase`. And in my `setUp` method I do `self::bootKernel()`.

What can I do to make my integration tests work with the correctly configured serializer?

Comment: Can you show the test itself? How do you get/create the serializer in the test? Can you see the normalizer in the container when using `bin/console debug:container <className>` and is the tag applied there?

Comment: I don't create the serializer. I extend the KernelTestCase class. So every Service should be automatically loaded and dependendy injection should work as normal. Shouldn't it?

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem. I was flagging the Serializer as public in `services_test.yaml` like this:

```
services:
    Symfony\Component\Serializer\Serializer:
        public: true
```

That seemed to mess with the instantiation of the service. I did not figure out how to flag the serializer as public and at the same time get a working instance. But I do not necessarily need it as a public service so I just removed the public flag.

If anyone knows how to flag the serializer as public in `services_test.yaml` and at the same time get a working instance the solution would be much appreciated none the less.